# Generate LINQ classes with SPMetal for Site Collection in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, linq-to-sharepoint

I try to generate LINQ classes for my Site Collection root in Sharepoint with this command (all in one line):

```
SPMetal.exe
/web:http://myserver 
/namespace:mynamespace 
/code:myfile.cs 
/parameters:mysettings.xml
```

The mysettings.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Web AccessModifier="Internal"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SharePoint/2009/spmetal">
    <List Name="List1"/>
    <List Name="List2"/>
    <ExcludeOtherLists/>
</Web>
```

But it doesn't work, the resulting error is (roughly translated from German):

> The specified file name can not be used. Perhaps already a file or 
>   directory with this name exists, or permissions are not sufficient 
>   to access the file.

And I think it can't be a file problem because:

1. If I change the web URL to `http://myserver/subsite` it works pretty good, the file gets generated
2. I can see the file being created with 0kb and after 1-2 seconds the file gets deleted and the error message is shown
3. I have more than enough space and permissions are ok as well (see 1.)

So what am I missing? Or can't I create LINQ classes for the root Site Collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 try [LINQ to SharePoint extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/993df7ed-2dd2-44e4-98f2-e6233812692b?SRC=VSIDE). It allows to use nice UI wizard for generating models classes.

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of that tool, thank you! I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, this tool works great and I don't get the error I got by using SPMetal directly.